# How to avoid fire while making my own electric bulb ? Can it create fire?

Tags: visible-light, electricity, batteries

When I take a battery, and then connect the 2 sides with a very thin pice of copper, it effectively lights up, but it create smoke upside. Can it create unintentional fire ?

Comment: It's not good to short-circuit any battery, and it can be dangerous. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/499980

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Be very careful.

Real light bulbs are filled with Argon or helium, an inert gas which prevents oxidation and fire